# How to split one column into two columns in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a contig file loaded in pandas like this:

```
    >NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676
1       AATTAATGAAATAAAGCAAGAAGACAAGGTTAGACAAAAAAAAGAG...
2       CAAAGCCTCCAAGAAATATGGGACTATGTGAAAAGACCAAATCTAC...
3       CCTGAAAGTGACGGGGAGAATGGAACCAAGTTGGAAAACACTCTGC...
4       GAGAACTTCCCCAATCTAGCAAGGCAGGCCAACATTCAAATTCAGG...
5       CCACAAAGATACTCCTCGAGAAGAGCAACTCCAAGACACATAATTG...
6       GTTGAAATGAAGGAAAAAATGTTAAGGGCAGCCAGAGAGAAAGGTC...
7       GGGAAGCCCATCAGACTAACAGCGGATCTCTCGGCAGAAACCCTAC...
8       TGGGGGCCAATATTCAACATTCTTAAAGAAAAGAATTTTCAACCCA...
9       GCCAAACTAAGCTTCATAAGCAAAGGAGAAATAAAATCCTTTACAG...
10      AGAGATTTTGTCACCACCAGGCCTGCCTTACAAGAGCTCCTGAAGG...
11      GAAAGGAAAAACCGGTACCAGCCACTGCAAAATCATGCCAAACTGT...
12      CTAGGAAGAAACTGCATCAACTAATGAGCAAAATAACCAGCTAACA...
13      TCAAATTCACACATAACAATATTAACCTTAAATGTAAATGGGCTAA...
14      AGACACAGACTGGCAAATTGGATAAAGAGTCAAGACCCATCAGTGT...
15      ACCCATCTCAAATGCAGAGACACACATAGGCTCAAAATAAAGGGAT...
16      CAAGCAAATGGAAAACAAAAAAAGGCAGGGGTTGCAATCCTAGTCT...
17      TTTAAACCAACAAAGATCAAAAGAGACAAAGAAGGCCATTACATAA...
18      ATTCAACAAGAAGAGCTAACTATCCTAAATATATATGCACCCAATA...
19      TTCATAAAGCAAGTCCTCAGTGACCTACAAAGAGACTTAGACTCCC...
20      GGAGACTTTAACACCCCACTGTCAACATTAGACAGATCAACGAGAC...
21      GATATCCAGGAATTGAACTCAGCTCTGCACCAAGCGGACCTAATAG...
22      CTCCACCCCAAATCAACAGAATATACATTCTTTTCAGCACCACACC...
23      ATTGACCACATAGTTGGAAGTAAAGCTCTCCTCAGCAAATGTAAAA...
24      ACAAACTGTCTCTCAGACCACAGTGCAATCAAATTAGAACTCAGGA...
25      CAAAACTGCTCAACTACATGAAAACTGAACAACCTGCTCCTGAATG...
26      AACAAAATGAAGGCAGAAATAAAGATGTTCTTTGAAACCAATGAGA...
27      TACCAGAATCTCTGGGACGCATTCAAAGCAGTGTGTAGAGGGAAAT...
28      GCCCACAAGAGAAAGCAGGAAAGATCTAAAATTGACACCCTAACAT...
29      CTAGAGAAGCAAGAGCAAACACATTCAAAAGCTAGCAGAAGGCAAG...
                              ...                        
8540                         >NODE_2518_length_56_cov_219
8541    CCCTTGTTGGTGTTACAAAGCCCTTGAACTACATCAGCAAAGACAA...
8542                         >NODE_2519_length_56_cov_174
8543    CCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCTCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCTCGA...
8544                         >NODE_2520_length_56_cov_131
8545    CCCAGGAGACTTGTCTTTGCTGATGTAGTTCAAGAGCTTTGTAACA...
8546                         >NODE_2521_length_56_cov_118
8547    GGCTCCCTATCGGCTCGAATTCCGCTCGACTATTATCGAATTCCGC...
8548                          >NODE_2522_length_56_cov_96
8549    CCCGCCCCCAGGAGACTTGTCTTTGCTGATAGTAGTCGAGCGGAAT...
8550                          >NODE_2523_length_56_cov_74
8551    AGAGACTTGTCTTTGCTGATGTAGTTCAAGGGCTTTGTAACACCGA...
8552                          >NODE_2524_length_56_cov_70
8553    TGCTCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCTCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCT...
8554                          >NODE_2525_length_56_cov_59
8555    GAGACCCTTGTCGGTGTTACAAAGCCCTTTAACTACATCAGCAAAG...
8556                          >NODE_2526_length_56_cov_48
8557    CCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCTCGACTACTATCGAATTCCGCTCGA...
8558                          >NODE_2527_length_56_cov_44
8559    CCAAGGGCTTTGTAACACCGACAAGGGTCTCGAAAACATCGGCATT...
8560                          >NODE_2528_length_56_cov_42
8561    GAGACCCTTGTAGGTGTTACAAAGCCCTTGAACTACATCAGCAAAG...
8562                          >NODE_2529_length_56_cov_38
8563    GAGACCCTTGTCGGTGTCACAAAGCCCTTGAACTACATCAGCAAAG...
8564                          >NODE_2530_length_56_cov_29
8565    GAGGGCTTTGTAACACCGACAAGGGTCTCGAAAACATCGGCATTCT...
8566                          >NODE_2531_length_56_cov_26
8567    AGGTTCAAGGGCTTTGTAACACCGACAAGGGTCTCGAAAACATCGG...
8568                          >NODE_2532_length_56_cov_25
8569    GAGATGTGTATAAGAGACTTGTCTTTGCTGATGTAGTTCAAGGGCT...
```

How to split this one column into two columns, making >NODE_...... in one column and the corresponding sequence in another column? Another issue is the sequences are in multiple lines, how to make them into one string? The result is expected like this:

```
    contig                                  sequence
    NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676         AAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
    NODE_........                          TTTTTTTTTTTTTTT
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce your example, but my guess is that you are loading file with pandas that is not formatted in a tabular format. From your example it looks like your file is formatted:

```
>Identifier
    sequence
>Identifier
    sequence
```

You would have to parse the file before you can put the information into a pandas dataframe. The logic would be to loop through each line of your file, if the line starts with '>Node' you store the line as an identifier. If not you concatenate them to the sequence value. Something like this:

```
testfile = '>NODE_1_length_4014_cov_1.97676\nAAAAAAAATTTTTTCCCCCCCGGGGGG\n>NODE_2518_length_56_cov_219\nAAAAAAAAGCCCTTTTT'.split('\n')
identifiers = []
sequences = []
current_sequence = ''
for line in testfile:
     if line.startswith('>'):
         identifiers.append(line)
         sequences.append(current_sequence)
         current_sequence = ''
     else:
         current_sequence += line.strip('\n')

df = pd.DataFrame({'identifiers' = identifiers, 
                   'sequences' = sequences})
```

Whether this code works depends on the details of your input which you didn't provide, but that might get you started.

Comment: Thank you very much. Let me try.